# The dimension of a matrix as a subspace of $\cal{M}_{3 \times 3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I was going through Linear Algebra homework and ran into another problem that I struggled with.

> Determine the dimension of
>
> $$\left\{A \in M_{3\times3} : A\begin{pmatrix}
>     1 & 1 & 1 \\
>     1 & 0 & -1 \\
>     0 & 1 & 2 \\
>     \end{pmatrix}
> =   \begin{pmatrix}
>     0 & 0 & 0 \\
>     0 & 0 & 0\\
>     0 & 0 & 0 \\
>     \end{pmatrix}\right\}
> $$

I am really unsure of where to start from here. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let$$B=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\1&0&-1\\0&1&2\end{bmatrix}.$$Then $A.B=0\iff B^T.A^T=0^T=0$. But\begin{align}B^T.(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)&\iff\left\{\begin{array}{l}x+y=0\\x+z=0\\x-y+2z=0\end{array}\right.\\&\iff z=y=-x\end{align}So, $B^T.A^T=0$ if and only if $A$ is a matrix of the form$$\begin{bmatrix}a&-a&-a\\b&-b&-b\\c&-c&-c\end{bmatrix}.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: That is actually where I had gotten stuck, I was able to create the form of matrix A with those identical arbitrary elements, but was unsure about how to find the dimension of the arbitrary matrix A

Comment: @JohnSayle Try writing the given the above matrix, and writing it as a linear combination of three (constant) matrices, where $a, b, c$ are the coefficients. FYI, for future reference, please include the work you've already done in your questions. It means that we won't have to explain to you that which you already know, and will make your questions better received in general.

Comment: I think I figured it out, so there exists a value x such that a(x) = b and a value y such that a(y) = c.  Then you can put A into RREF such that the row of a's only remains, and since only one row is non-zero, thus rank(A) and also dim(A ).  Correct?  Edit: @TheoBendit just saw your comment and I will make sure to do that, I understand why that's important

Comment: It's much simpler than that:$$\begin{bmatrix}a&-a&-a\\b&-b&-b\\c&-c&-c\end{bmatrix}=a\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&-1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}+b\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\1&-1&-1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}+c\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\1&-1&-1\end{bmatrix}$$and the matrices$$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&-1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix},\ \begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\1&-1&-1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\text{, and }\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\1&-1&-1\end{bmatrix}$$are linearly independent. Therefore, your space is $3$-dimensional.